# C# : is it possible to run .NET Framework console application together with ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, .net-4.8

I have created a project using a console application in C# with .NET Framework, and I would like to integrate ASP.NET MVC into this project.

While I understand that there is a .NET Core console application with MVC, I am building a project that is only supported by Windows and I want to build a self-hosted application. Therefore, I need to use .NET Framework together with the functions provided by ASP.NET MVC. Is this possible?

- .NET Framework 4.8
- Console application (generates .exe file)
- ASP.NET MVC

If this is possible, does anyone know any links where I can follow to create this project?

Comment: Wait, I'm confused. What is "MVC" here? The general design pattern? ASP.NET MVC? What are you trying to do? Why do you need a view for a console app?

Comment: What do you want to do, run an ASP.NET MVC app from a _server_ running on a console app? Or do you want to create a console app that uses the MVC pattern to do something (and if so, what)?

Comment: Also, .NET Core is supported on Windows too.

Comment: Why rely on a dying platform (.net framework) and not use current technology (.NET > 5)?

Comment: @EtiennedeMartel I am trying to build a self-hosted application and I read up that it requires a console application to build the .exe file. MVC stands for model view controller.

Comment: @Flydog57 Run an ASP.NET MVC application from a server running on a console application. So if I click on the .exe file in the bin folder, it starts running the MVC and I can launch the website.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible.

> ASP.NET MVC apps [are hosted in IIS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/porting-existing-aspnet-apps/hosting-differences)

Comment: ASP.NET Core apps, however, can run as a standalone executable, using Kestrel for serving requests.

Comment: @EtiennedeMartel Yes, but Kestrel cannot be used in .net Framework console applications

Comment: @NineBerry Can I then build a ASP.NET MVC with .NET Framework and also produce a .exe file at the same time without relying on the Console Application?

Comment: ASP.net MVC only runs in IIS. But you can use ASP.net Core as a standalone application but only with .NET 5 or higher. When starting a new project, why rely on outdated .net Framework? .NET > 5 is the future.

Comment: @NineBerry I understand but I have a project that requires me to rely on using the .NET Framework :(